# How to choose substitution to make the difference equation linear with fixed coefficients?

Tags: intuition, dynamical-systems, recurrence-relations

I am going over some lecture notes and there is the following exercise:

> Solve $$(k+1)^{2}y(k+1)-k^{2}y(k)=1$$ with the initial condition
>   $$y(1)=0$$

where $k$ it for the time, hence not constant.

The solution defines $$z(k):=k^{2}y(k)$$ and this gives the linear
with fixed coefficients equation: $$z(k+1)-z(k)=1$$ with $$z(1)=0$$

**My question is this:** How do I know how to choose $z(k)$ s.t I will
get a linear equation with fixed coefficients ? is there some calculation
that may lead me to such $z(k)$ or is it just a guess ?

Comment: It can't always be done, and I doubt there is a systematic method for when it can, just as there is no sure fire way to make u-substitutions in integrals. However, just as for integrals, if you can do a substitution, experience will often let you guess the right one.

Comment: @Aaron - true, but if I would of asked about some substitution in integrals usually there is some intuition behind it. this is not about the general case, but on this example

Comment: The Intuition is trying to rearrange things to get things into a form resembling Andre's answer.  If it can be done, it is likely (but perhaps not always) entirely straight forward manner. The big trick is just knowing to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, precisely the same substitution would be made for 
$$af(k+1)y(k+1)+bf(k)y(k)=c,$$
where $f(j)$ is any fixed function which is nowhere $0$, and $a$, $b$, $c$ are constants.

Comment: This is a very nice and general result. Is there another such result that you can please mention ? (+1) and I will accept soon

Comment: Sorry, nothing else obvious springs to mind.

Comment: It is worth adding that you can do similar substitutions for the more general form $ag(k+1,y(k+1)))+bg(k,y(k))=c$.  For example, $k+1/y(k+1)+k/y(k)=1$ would use the substitution $x(k)=k/y(k)$.

Comment: @Aaron where $g$ is any fixed function with two variables ?

Comment: @belgi: yes, that is correct.